# What is the word for showing affection for a certain team just for the sake of it?

Tags: american-english

I like a football team or show support for them purely because when I was being raised, everyone around me used to like that team. So I like them but its not like I care if they win or lose. Is there a word for that in English?

Comment: *Fair-weather fan* covers much of this idea, except that it often emphasizes that you only pay attention to the team when it is doing well.  If that's part of your behavior, then that may be the best phrase.

Comment: Its more like I pay attention to the team when there is no other sports going on that I like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would just be called a *casual fan*.

Answer (score 1):

You support the team *for sentimental reasons*, or, perhaps, *for old-times' sake.*

It may also be that you are loyal, and faithful.

Comment: Its more like I support the team because everyone around me supported it.

Comment: They feel like (extended) 'family'?

Answer (score 0):

**Team sympathizer** may fit.

> Definition: someone who backs the team and hopes that it will be
>   successful.